# Example of a proper, dense ideal in a unital Banach algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, banach-algebras

I know that if ${\cal A}$ is a non- unital Banach algebra, then ${\cal A}$ may contain some proper, dense ideals. I need an example of a proper, dense ideal in a unital Banach algebra or show that it does not contain any  proper, dense ideal. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ no identity, I need an example in a unital Banach algebra, while $c_0$ is not unital.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a unital Banach algebra the set of invertible elements is open and nonvoid, hence the set of noninvertible elements is closed ( and also nonvoid, since it contains zero). Any proper ideal is contained in the set of noninvertible elements. Hence, no dense proper ideals in a unital Banach algebra.

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer

Comment: No worries. Oh, a consequence of the result above is that any maximal ideal ( left, right or bilateral) is closed.